# TYPO3 tt_news update script shows empty page

Tags: typo3, tt-news

After updating my TYPO3 CMS from 4.3 to 4.5 LTS the news were no longer displayed. So i decided to update tt_news extension as well. It was at version 2.5.2 and had to be upgraded to the newest 3.4.0. It suggested to me, to use its own 'update script' (and as mentioned at other resources too) to work properly because of serious changes. Under 'Extentension Manager' - 'tt_news' - 'UPDATE!' it shows up with a simple blank page and nothing can be done.

Is there any hint to solve this?

Comment: What does the Apache/PHP Error log say?

Comment: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/44091

Comment: After checking php error log, so i found this site too. It fixed my problem! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got some PHP error. Copy the /var/log/apache2/error.log or enable in TYPO3 Install Tool configuration PHP errors.

Comment: This is correct. I found out where PHP struggled. So I was lead to the site mentioned above in the comments. Thanks!